# How to simplify Log expressions using rules

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression,

```
(Cot[(t1 - t2)/2]*((4*I)*t1^3 - (9*I)*t1^2*x + 
   (6*I)*t1*x^2 - (2*I)*x^3 - 
   12*x*Cot[(t1 - x)/2] - 12*x*Cot[x/2] + 
   3*x^2*Csc[(t1 - x)/2]^2 - 
   3*x^2*Csc[x/2]^2 + 
   6*t1^2*Log[1 - E^((-I)*(t1 - x))] - 
   12*t1*x*Log[1 - E^((-I)*(t1 - x))] + 
   6*x^2*Log[1 - E^((-I)*(t1 - x))] - 
   12*t1^2*Log[1 - E^(I*(t1 - x))] + 
   12*t1*x*Log[1 - E^(I*(t1 - x))] - 
   6*x^2*Log[1 - E^((-I)*x)] - 
   24*Log[Sin[(t1 - x)/2]] + 
   6*t1^2*Log[Sin[(t1 - x)/2]] + 
   24*Log[Sin[x/2]] + (12*I)*(t1 - x)*
    PolyLog[2, E^((-I)*(t1 - x))] + 
   (12*I)*t1*PolyLog[2, E^(I*(t1 - x))] - 
   (12*I)*x*PolyLog[2, E^((-I)*x)] + 
   12*PolyLog[3, E^((-I)*(t1 - x))] - 
   12*PolyLog[3, E^((-I)*x)]))/9
```

I made two rules

```
rule1 = u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> 
  u*Log[v*w]; rule2 = -u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> u*Log[w/v];
```

To collect Log, but still it is not collecting them. What am I doing wrong ? I don't want to FullSimplify because it is running for long time.

Comment: @mikado, Sorry I didn't get your comment.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was partly incorrect, so I've deleted it.  I find it difficult to make rules work if their Left Hand Side is too complicated.  I think this is the problem here.

Comment: See I made a simpler rule. rule2 = -x_*Log[a_] :> x*Log[1/a]; this works when I have an arbitrary function. But as soon as a constant appears, it stops working.

Comment: I think that when you have a rule with terms added (as in your rule1) there are many ways Mathematica can try to match it to your expression.  I don't think it is trying them all, so misses some that you can see.

Comment: so what should be done ? because I am NOT interesting in expanding and then fullsimplify

Comment: If I scrape-n-paste just your eight Logs into a separate list and I try to reorder them to find pairs of logs that match your pattern then I don't see any such pair. Mathematica pattern matching is very brute force. It never, well probably almost never, sees two expressions that are obviously the same if you just use algebra on them and thus it decides they match. It only matches expressions of literally exactly the same form. `6*t1^2*Log[1 - E^((-I)*(t1 - x))]+6*t1^2*Log[1 - E^((-I)*(t1 - x))]/.u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> u*Log[v*w]` "works" because both those are exactly the same form.

Comment: I've tried manipulating your expression, and can't see any obviously simpler form.

Comment: Well I'll get simple expression when I write sin in terms of exp and the log cancels with the exp and i'll get linear function upto constant. Hence I am trying atleast collect them first and then do the change into exp

Comment: It might not look straightforward now but the full expression is simplified if I take appropriate domains

Comment: Your logs have complex numbers in them, so you can't apply these composition rules of real valued logs to them if you don't want to make the expression wrong.

Comment: @Kagaratsch : I agree but it is true in restricted domain. For instance plot real or imaginary value of (Log[1-Exp[Ix]] - Log[Sin[x]]]) and Log[(1-Exp[ix]/Sin[x])]  they match when $x\in (0,2\pi)$